# Android new SDK tools (r.14) does not generate AIDL files

Tags: android

My project was running just fine and my AIDL files were generated in the GEN folder. 
After i installed the new SDK tools (r.14) the AIDL are not generated anymore.

Any idea why?

P.S. the aidl.exe file exist in the platform-tools directory.

Comment: Have you tried the good old 'clean project'?

Comment: The upgrade to 14 changes some build configuration files. It tries to automatically upgrade some in Eclipse but this seems to be a little problematic for more complex projects. You might try running 'android upgrade project' on your project, to try to get all the build files in the correct state or just set up a new project using your current source.